# Images and styles are not appearing in HTML email

Tags: c#, html, css, .net

My image and styles are not appearing in the email (in Outlook 2016). This is how I'm doing it:

c#:

```
var body = File.ReadAllText("c:/emailtemplate.html");
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("noreply@mycompany.com", "you@outlook.com", "test", body);
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
var client = new SmtpClient(SmtpHost);
client.Send(msg);
```

emailtemplate.html

```
<div style="border:solid 1px #000;padding:20px;">
   <img src="logo.png" style="width:250px">
   <p style="color:red;font-weight:bold">Thanks for signing up!</p>
</div>
```

logo.png is in same location as emailtemplate.html

Any idea how I can include the image and apply the styles to my email message?

Answer (score 0):

Use full URL to the image and not its relative URL.

Something like: http://www.example.com/logo.gif

Comment: Adding a full URL fixes the image issue, but I also had to make sure that the URL is accessible by the email client. Still having trouble with CSS. Some of my styles (like color) are being applied, but most are not (padding, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Your img src should be at least absolute to have chance to be visible.
To guarantee img visible convert it to base64 string and create `LinkedResource`.
Also create `AlternateView` and attach it to `MailMessage` instance. All these features are in `System.Net.Mail` namespace. Here is an example in VB.NET to help you.

```
<div style="border:solid 1px #000;padding:20px;">
   <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,####" style="width:250px">
   <p style="color:red;font-weight:bold">Thanks for signing up!</p>
</div>

Dim lnkRcs As New List(Of Net.Mail.LinkedResource)
Dim match As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(msgBody, "src=""(?<src>data:(?<mime>.+?);base64,(?<data>.+?))""")
Dim a As Integer = 0
While match.Success
    Dim stm = Convert.FromBase64String(match.Groups("data").Value)
    Dim rc As New Net.Mail.LinkedResource(New System.IO.MemoryStream(stm), match.Groups("mime").Value)
    rc.ContentId = "rc" & a
    rc.TransferEncoding = Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64
    msgBody = msgBody.Replace(match.Groups("src").Value, "cid:" & rc.ContentId)
    lnkRcs.Add(rc)
    a += 1
    match = match.NextMatch()
End While
Dim altHtml As Net.Mail.AlternateView = Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(msgBody, Nothing, "text/html")
For Each rc As Net.Mail.LinkedResource In lnkRcs
    altHtml.LinkedResources.Add(rc)
Next
msg.AlternateViews.Add(altHtml)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot. I did get the image working using a full image path accessible by the client.

Comment: full path *allows* but not guarantees.  Recipient have to allow / show images. I had all these problems. this is why I use this code.