# Embedded image not working for email

Tags: c#, image, smtp

I am trying to send an email with an embedded Image.

This is my html.

```
<tr>
    <td><img src="cid:imageCode" /></td>
</tr>
```

This is the C# Code,

```
        var mailDefinition = new MailDefinition();
        mailDefinition.BodyFileName = fileName ;
        mailDefinition.From = "from@gmail.com";
        using (var mailMessage = mailDefinition.CreateMailMessage("to@gmail.com", replacements, new LiteralControl()))
        {
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail);
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.Subject = subject;
            var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(mailMessage.Body, Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

            var imgRes = new LinkedResource("C:\\images\\image.gif", System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
            imgRes.ContentId = "imageCode";
            imgRes.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imgRes);
            mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);


            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                client.Send(mailMessage);
            }
        }
```

I receive the email, but the image attachment doesn't work,  When i check through developer tools, i see this.

```
<img blockedimagesrc="cid:imageCode">
```

I am wondering how does this gets inserted into my html ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know "imgCode" != "imageCode"?

Comment: Yes, That was a typo.

Comment: This might be of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398374/images-and-styles-are-not-appearing-in-html-email/37398692

Comment: Just noted that you are linking a gif file and the MimeType is Jpeg

Comment: Thanks @BharatGupta that was the issue.Its working now.